# Como mandar a llamar una función de js simulando un doble click al botón ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, function

Tengo la siguiente función dentro de un jsp, lo que hace es limpiar los campos del formulario, lo que quiero es que al darle click al botón que manda a llamar esa función simule un doble click

```html
function limpiarCampos(){

$('idPers').val("");
$('nomPers').val("");
$('rfcPerson').val("");



}
```

y este es el botón que manda a llamar la función

```html
<input type="button" onclick="limpiarCampos()"></input>
```

como le puedo hacer para que simule un doble click al mandar a llamar a la función?
Gracias

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres por simular un doble clic? ¿Quieres que se llame dos veces la misma función?

Comment: Asi  es, que se mandé a llamar dos veces

Comment: ¿Por qué quisieras llamar la misma función 2 veces de manera consecutiva? Igualmente, podrías intentar utilizar la función `setTimeout()` y que ésta llame de nuevo a `limpiarCampos()` después de unos mili segundos.

Comment: Y en mi botón mando a llamar a setTimeout()?

Comment: Mira este [ejemplo](https://embed.plnkr.co/dTBTOc1V7wXDilrPjI3F/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes llamarla de inmediato con

```
<input type="button" onclick="limpiarCampos();limpiarCampos()"></input>
```

O Hacer el timeout que sugiere Miller

Answer (score 0):

Seguro que hay formas más ortodoxas y correctas pero se me ocurre esto para que puedas salir del paso:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>


     <script>
      function setFocus(num){
          document.getElementById("boton").style.display="none";
          document.getElementById("boton2").style.display="block";
          //setTimeout(limpiarCampos, 3000);
      }
    </script>
    
    <script>
      
      function limpiarCampos() {
        alert("Dentro de la función");
        document.getElementById("boton2").style.display="none";
          document.getElementById("boton").style.display="block";
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form name="formulario">
    <input id="boton" type="button" value="Botón" onclick="setFocus();" ></input>
    <input id="boton2" hidden="true" type="button" value="Botón"    onclick="limpiarCampos()" id="mySelect1"></input>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: releyendo tu pregunta, no se si querías concretamente ésta funcionalidad. Si no es así, dímelo y la borro para no dejar código no válido para la respuesta.